# How do you get emacs to recognize .m files as Matlab files, not objective-C files?

Tags: matlab, emacs, dot-emacs

My .emacs file concerning Matlab is as follows:

```
;; Matlab mode
(autoload    'matlab-mode "matlab" "Matlab Editing Mode" t)
(setq matlab-indent-function t)
(setq matlab-shell-command "matlab")
```

But when I open a Matlab file, I see I'm in Objective-C mode. Since I do not plan on writing Objective-C anytimes soon, how do I default all .m files to open in Matlab mode?

Comment: googling `emacs add-to-list auto-mode` should give you what you want.

Comment: @orzechowskid -- Please post an answer with a sample for `.m` files and `matlab-mode` so that someone can find the solution in the future by Googling something like "matlab .m emacs file type".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your comment says you've resolved this. Something tells me you did it by adding

```
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.m" . matlab-mode))
```

to your `.emacs`. I've got so many of these sprinkled around that I just wrote a convenience macro for it:

```
(defmacro by-extension (ext mode)
  `(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '(,(format "\\.%s" ext) . ,mode)))
```

which lets me write things like

```
(by-extension "m" matlab-mode)
```